# What is the difference between XMLSchema and RDFSchema?

Tags: xml, xsd, rdf, rdfs

I read a few articles about it but i'm not so sure if i got it right!

Reading [this article](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/RDF-XML) i think that the main difference is that RDF describes a data model (and rdfs the meaning of the vocabulary) in difference to xml which just structures information. is this correct?

Comment: XMLSchema is to XML as RDFSchema is to RDF. Not sure what more one can say. It would be easier to say what the similarities are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's basically correct.

[XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) is for the definition of XML documents in general.  It provides the *e**X**tensibility* in XML (e**X**Tensible Markup Language), much like DTDs have done, but with improvements to typing and an XML-based syntax.

[RDF Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) provides a data-modelling vocabulary for RDF (Resource Description Framework) data.  As a semantic extension of RDF, RDF Schema describes relationships between groups of related resources.

In very broad terms, XML Schema is more concerned with defining *syntactic* structure; RDF Schema, with *semantic* structure.